# The value of attribute "Is Active" must be set -error always when trying to create category via SOAP

Tags: category, magento2.2, soap-api-v1

I'm trying to create a category via SOAP

```
    $category_data = [
    'parentId' => 2,
    'name' => 'NIMI',
    'is_active' => 1, // also tried 'isActive' => 1
    'position' => 1,
    'includeInMenu' => 1,
    'category' => 1,
];
// $category_client     $category_client = new SoapClient(
    'http://host/soap?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1', $category_client->catalogCategoryRepositoryV1Save($category_data);
```

I'm getting an error `Could not save category: %1`
with details `The value of attribute "Is Active" must be set`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **store_id** to your data.
Maybe it will be helpful.

Check keys value, because **includeInMenu** and **parentId** should be like **parent_id / include_in_menu**

```
$category_data = [
'store_id' => 0,
'parent_id' => 2,
'name' => 'NIMI',
'is_active' => 1,
'position' => 1,
'include_in_menu' => 1,
'category' => 1
];
```